# Accessing JSON variable two levels down

Tags: php, json

This is some sample JSON data, which is an extract of the JSON data provided by EmojiOne project. They have released version 3.0 but their JSON format has changed slightly and the previous PHP code I had to extract data from the JSON no longer works.

**single.json**

```
{
  "1f469-2764-1f468": {
    "name": "couple with heart: woman, man",
    "category": "people",
    "order": 2426,
    "display": 0,
    "shortname": ":couple_with_heart_woman_man:",
    "code_points": {
      "base": "1f469-2764-1f468",
      "output": "1f469-200d-2764-fe0f-200d-1f468",
      "default_matches": [
        "1f469-200d-2764-fe0f-200d-1f468",
        "1f469-2764-fe0f-1f468"
      ],
      "greedy_matches": [
        "1f469-200d-2764-fe0f-200d-1f468",
        "1f469-2764-fe0f-1f468"
      ],
      "decimal": ""
    },
    "keywords": [
      "couple",
      "love",
      "man",
      "woman"
    ]
  }
}
```

And this is some PHP I'm using to try and extract data from the JSON:

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents('single.json');
$json_a = json_decode($str, true);

foreach($json_a as $key => $val) {

    $name = $val['name'];
    $shortname = $val['shortname'];
    $category = $val['category'];
    $emoji_order = $val['order'];
    $keywords = implode(',', $val['keywords']);

}
?>
```

How can I access the value of `base` from the `code_points` part of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$val` should be a [multidimensional array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), so you can access `base` by accessing it like this:

```
$val['code_points']['base'];
```

[Here](https://eval.in/780679) is an example of it in action, and a simple program:

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOT
{
  "1f469-2764-1f468": {
    "name": "couple with heart: woman, man",
    "category": "people",
    "order": 2426,
    "display": 0,
    "shortname": ":couple_with_heart_woman_man:",
    "code_points": {
      "base": "1f469-2764-1f468",
      "output": "1f469-200d-2764-fe0f-200d-1f468",
      "default_matches": [
        "1f469-200d-2764-fe0f-200d-1f468",
        "1f469-2764-fe0f-1f468"
      ],
      "greedy_matches": [
        "1f469-200d-2764-fe0f-200d-1f468",
        "1f469-2764-fe0f-1f468"
      ],
      "decimal": ""
    },
    "keywords": [
      "couple",
      "love",
      "man",
      "woman"
    ]
  }
}
EOT;

$json_a = json_decode($str, true);

foreach($json_a as $key => $val) {

    $name = $val['name'];
    $shortname = $val['shortname'];
    $category = $val['category'];
    $emoji_order = $val['order'];
    $keywords = implode(',', $val['keywords']);
    $base = $val['code_points']['base'];

    echo 'Name: ', $name, "\n";
    echo 'Base: ', $base;

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - that sorted it!